# Angular How to load css from server

Tags: css, angular

I want to try to load css from a server/external source intro angular. I'm trying to use the DomSanitizer already but without succes. The stylesheet is shown inside the network tab of chrome but the html does not apply the stylesheet.

[chrome networktab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvrSm.png)

Inside the TS file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
title = 'angulardynamicss';
cssUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/csspoc/asFile'

constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

And HTML looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("http://localhost:8080/api/csspoc/asFile")'>

<p class="test">hello</p>
```

The stylesheet file contains:

```
.test {
    background-color: blue;
}

p{
    color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: You should probably name your css file with the .css extension asFile.css for example. But I think the real problem is that you are not using the this keyword this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl in your html template.

Comment: Your right indeed, back-end made mistake. no no need to use this.sanitizer inside html file you can directly refer to sanitizer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you inject it in the AppComponent? Can you not just add the `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of your index.html?

Comment: it is inside the html? or do you mean inject inside child component?

Reason to do in app component because it's a playground file. So for testing purpose for real project. If this one works i will implement in real project. Now i know exactly witch library's where needed to make solution.